# Apply Special price if price in cart is higher to 350 if not apply normal price Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to set up a price rule in magento.

so,

```
If (Total in Sopping Cart is > 350us){

   Price of every products in Shopping cart is Special Price   

}
else{

   Price of every product in shopping cart is Normal Price

}
```

I wonder how do this with the two price in product setup, when you write a regular price anthem a special price, the regular price is crossing (disabled) and special price is enabled. That I need is play with the shopping cart rule and that prices.

How can i make this.

Thanks, please help me :)

Comment: This is kinda impossible in Magento by default. You would have to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Observer on Cart.for that you have to create a custom module and then you can call method of your observer and in that method you can put your check and also can implement price 
use this event

```
    <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

in custom module config.xml

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible if you purchase for 300 or more then apply special discount for the total amount.**

For this you have to create a rule. `Promotions->Shopping CatPrice Rules` and click `Add New Rule`.

In **Rule Information**

[image]

In **Conditions**

[image]

In **Actions**

[image]

And `Save` the rule.

Note: This is just an example, and this have difference from what you ask. So check this just for reference and don't know this is helpful or not.

Comment: I wonder how do this with the two price in product setup, when you write a regular price anthem a special price, the regular price is crossing (disabled) and special price is enabled. That I need is play with the shopping cart rule and that prices.